# Parse multiline output to array in shellscript

Tags: arrays, bash

I tried to fetch all repos from a git user and put them into a array within a shell script. Somehow the array doesn´t recognize the new line as a separator and acts like there´s only one multi line element within the array.

Here´s my sample code:

```
someUser=Joe
declare -a repos=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$someUser/repos?page=$PAGE&per_page=100" | grep -e 'git_url*' | cut -d \" -f 4 | cut -d"/" -f5 | cut -d"." -f1)

for repo in $repos; do
  echo $repo
  // some more stuff
done
```

The output from the curl and cut looks like that:

```
RepoA
RepoB
RepoC
[...]
```

How do I get a new line element treated as a new element within the array? I use the array several times so I need one fixed container with all the repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to iterate over the elements of a Bash array:

```
for repo in "${repos[@]}"; do
```

Also, to create an array with the output of a command, you need to wrap the `$(...)` subshell within `(...)`, like this:

```
declare -a repos=($(curl -s ...))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but i still get a faulty output :(

Still the first element in the array is the whole curl & cut output. 
[edit]

Comment: @Moka I noticed another problem in your script, fixed it now, see my updated post

Comment: Thanks @janos
The second fix with the additional bracket solved my problem. I´ll answer this question with the complete code :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @janos i fixed the script. The additionsl bracket within the delcare line was the problem. Here is the full code. Maybe somebody would like to copy it.

```
#!/bin/bash

gitUrl="https://github.com"
gitUser="foobar"
cloneCmd="git clone"
fetchCmd="git fetch"

magenta="\033[35m"
green="\033[32m"
def="\033[0m"

declare -a repos=($(curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$gitUser/repos?page=$PAGE&per_page=100" | grep -e 'git_url*' | cut -d \" -f 4 | cut -d"/" -f5 | cut -d"." -f1))

# Init clone
echo -e "$magenta Cloning new Repositories $def"
for repo in "${repos[@]}"
do
    if [ -d $repo ]; then
        echo -e "$green \tRepo $repo already exists $def"
        continue
    fi

    $cloneCmd $gitUrl/$gitUser/$repo

done
echo -e "$green Colning finished $def"

# Update Repos
echo -e "$magenta Updating Repositories $def"
for repo in "${repos[@]}"
do
    cd $repo
    $fetchCmd
    cd ..
done
echo -e "$green Update finished $def"
```

Comment: Do you seriously think anyone would want to use your broken script? 1. You're using a broken way to populate the array: use `mapfile` or `read` to properly populating it. 2. You're parsing json using chains of `grep`s and `cut`s: broken and inefficient. Use a proper parser, e.g., `jq`. 3. You're putting code in variables. Code isn't data (this is not Lisp). Use a function instead. 4. Use more quotes. 5. Don't use hardcoded ANSI escape sequences. Use `tput`. I've probably missed a few antipatterns `:)`.

Comment: Ok :D I'll try to fix those mistakes. I'm no professional but thanks for your ideas.